# How to get all of the pasted string, in input which has a maxLength attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, string, clipboard, paste

I need to get all of the pasted string in input which has a maxLength attribute.

But in 'onpaste' event there is no property to get all of the pasted string.

For example, check below snippet with this string:

"AAAAA-BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB"

The output is : "AAAAA"

But I need all of the string.

```js
const onPasteFn = (e) => {
  setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = e.target.value, 0)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" maxLength="5" onpaste="onPasteFn(event)" />

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Why are you setting the `maxLength` to 5 if you need more than that?

Comment: @RahulBhobe this is a small piece of code from a bigger script, I need all of the string but the maxLength is neccessary

Comment: Check the length in JavaScript

Comment: Ideally, you cannot get the whole string by restricting the input to some limited length. So,  if you can tell us what exactly you are trying to achieve with the entire string. It would be helpful

Comment: @RahulBhobe I need to put maxLength to 5, Actually in 'onpaste ' event if you log "event" there is no property that saves all of the pasted string

Comment: OK -  As far as I can tell the behavior you see is expected.
There seems to be another answer posted that reads from the clipboard directly instead of the event - if that is what you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider using `clipboardData` from the event, where you can use [`getData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/getData) to grab the text that was pasted from the clipboard like so:

```js
const onPasteFn = (e) => {
  document.getElementById("demo").textContent = (e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" maxLength="5" onpaste="onPasteFn(event)" />

<p id="demo"></p>
```

See example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event#Live_example) from the docs. Note that the fallback of `|| window.clipboardData` is used for IE support.

Answer (score 2):

You can access `clipboardData` through function `getData()`, and print it instead of `e.target.value()`. If you store it in a temporary variable, like I did in my example, you are able to perform further elaboration on the pasted string.

It works for *reasonably* recent versions of browsers (for example **FF 22+**).

```js
const onPasteFn = (e) => {
  var myData = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
  
  setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myData, 0)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" maxLength="5" onpaste="onPasteFn(event)" />

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a higher `maxLength` if the pasted string is expected to be larger. Your sample input string has length 29. So here is modified code with `maxLength=30`.

```js
const onPasteFn = (e) => {
  setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = e.target.value, 0)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" maxLength="30" onpaste="onPasteFn(event)" />

<p id="demo"></p>
```